# &nbsp when inspecting the element?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When I inspect the element in Chrome dev tools I see the following

Why do I see this element? `&nbsp` and how can I remove it?

```
<div>Word1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: It means there's a *non-breaking space*.

Comment: How do I remove it?

Comment: Double click it to enter the edit mode and then delete it. Or just don't add it in the first place.

Comment: Got it, It's a response from an API, will remove the spaces, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`&nbsp;` means 'Non-Breaking Space'. In a WYSIWYG (What you see is what you get) text editor you can just press space a bunch of times to get a larger space. But in HTML it would just read multiple spaces as one. So that code you pasted should show as "Word1      ".

Answer (score 1):

`&nbsp` represents the non-breaking space [entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity).

Here's an excerpt from the [MDN docs](http://%20Entities%20are%20frequently%20used%20to%20display%20reserved%20characters%20(which%20would%20otherwise%20be%20interpreted%20as%20HTML%20code),%20and%20invisible%20characters%20(like%20non-breaking%20spaces).%20You%20can%20also%20use%20them%20in%20place%20of%20other%20characters%20that%20are%20difficult%20to%20type%20with%20a%20standard%20keyboard.) on entities:

> Entities are frequently used to display reserved characters (which
> would otherwise be interpreted as HTML code), and invisible characters
> (like non-breaking spaces). You can also use them in place of other
> characters that are difficult to type with a standard keyboard.